# Show that $e^x + x$ is bijective

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x) = e^x + x$. Since $e^x + x$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ we have $f'(x) = e^x +1> 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and hence injective. For surjectivity my textbook gives me the hint to use the intermediate value theorem. Is this really necessary here, since $f$ defined on hole $\mathbb{R}$ and is injective?

How would one use the intermediate value in this case (since the interval is $(-\infty, \infty)$)?

Comment: $\arctan(x)$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, is injective, but not onto (all of $\mathbb{R}$).  In fact, it's bounded.

Comment: $e^x$ is injective without being surjective, for example.

Comment: @Evariste ups, yes I changed it.

Comment: The argument that injectivity $\Leftrightarrow$ surjectivity only works when the map is on a finite set, ie, for a mapping $f\colon X\to X$ on a finite set $X$, it is true that $f$ is injective iff $f$ is surjective. However, this fails when $X$ is an infinite set, as the counterexamples in the comments show.

Comment: If $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and if $f'\left(x\right)> c > 0$ for some constant $c$ and all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is bijective. (The injectivity follows from your reasoning. The surjectivity follows from similar reasoning to José's excellent answer below - you can use the mean value theorem to determine that the limit at $\infty$ is $\infty$ and the limit at $-\infty$ is $-\infty$, and the intermediate value theorem to then conclude surjectivity.)  In this case, we have $f'\left(x\right)>1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and we can take $c = 1$.)

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, $f'(x)=e^x+1$, not $e^x$.

And the exponential function is also injective and it's defined in the whole $\Bbb R$; however, it is not surjective.

Note that$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x+x=\infty\quad\text{and that}\quad\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x+x=-\infty.\tag1$$So, if $y\in\Bbb R$, take $x_0\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x_0)\geqslant y$ and take $x_1\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x_1)\leqslant y$; they exist, by $(1)$. So, by the intermediate value theorem between $x_0$ and $x_1$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: So I just say: Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Then choose $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(a)\le y \le f(b)$ so we can use the intermediate value theorem on $[f(a), f(b)]$ to find some $c$ s.t. $f(c)  = y$?

Comment: I don't see how that would work. Is there something wrong in my answer?

Comment: no, there's nothing wrong with your answer, but why would this approach not work? (I can't accept it yet)

Comment: You've edited your comment. I agree with what you wrote now.